# Handle promise rejection without rejecting the promise that calls it?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

I want the promise catch block to not make the promise fail, I just want to return false when it doesnt pan out! How can I do this?

I tried wrapping the reject in a try catch block but it didn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/2fz69ea2/1/

```
var passing_promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success');
});

// I want this function to just return false, 
var failing_promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  reject('Failure');
 })
.then(() => {
  return true;
})
.catch(() => {
  return false;
})

passing_promise.then(()=>{
  return failing_promise()
}).then((ret) => {
  console.log('please print false.. please! ', ret)
})
.catch(() => {
  console.log('I Never want to make it here, but as it stands I do')
})
```

I also wonder if this means I am misusing promises. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing

```
.catch(() => {
  return false;
})
```

is correct. This will *resolve* the promise to `false`.

Your problem is a typo:

```
 return failing_promise()
```

`failing_promise` is not a function, you cannot call it. It should just be

```
return failing_promise
```

```js
var passing_promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success');
});

// I want this function to just return false, 
var failing_promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  reject('Failure');
 })
.then(() => {
  return true;
})
.catch(() => {
  return false;
})

passing_promise.then(()=>{
  return failing_promise
}).then((ret) => {
  console.log('please print false.. please! ', ret)
})
.catch(() => {
  console.log('I Never want to make it here, but as it stands I do')
})
```

Comment: Ok, awesome.

I have a mocha test that does this but it leads to the catch block of the test and the test fails! Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: what if failing_promise had parameters?

Comment: I don't think I understand. In your example, `failing_promise` is a **promise**. Promises don't have parameters. Of course if you have a function that *returns* a promise, then you would call it: `return somethingThatRetursnAPromise(and, args);`. But I'm just working with what  you posted.

Comment: This was so helpful. I was returning a Mongoose.findOne().then which  I assumed behaved like new Promise, but I wrapped it in a return new Promise and it works now. 

Thanks so much!

Comment: `.then` returns a promise, yes. You shouldn't have to put that inside yet another promise.

Comment: That is what I expected, but if I don't then it goes into the catch block of the test. I was returning undefined in the catch block of the function being tested, which would evaluate...but it would still lead to the catch block in the test.